# how to solve problem getting json object element

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a json object that i want to use.

```
    {
    "type": "PROVIDER_PAYLOAD",
    "message": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkOTQ3OTg4N2RlMGRkMDc4ZjEzM2FmNyIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWxzb25nZHVuc3RhbjJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSIiwiaWF0IjoxNTcwMDI3MDA4fQ.FcpoBPmhTSX535bNgE2ezCCWsNFPjEhc87hM4y6WadM"
}
```

so when i try to access it using

```
console.log("Postback: " + payload.type)
```

but i get an error of

```
Postback: undefined
```

i have looked over some resources on the web and most of them do it this way and it works but i am not sure why mine is not giving the value for type
thanks in advance

Comment: Better Use `JSON.parse(payload) `before accessing the keys.

Comment: @Shubh yah it has worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subh is right. You have to parse the JSON into an object before accessing `type` using `payload.type` syntax.

So, let's say you have the following:

```js
let payload = {
    "type": "PROVIDER_PAYLOAD",
    "message": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzWadM"
}
```

You have to convert it into a JS object using `JSON.parse`:

```js
let payloadObj = JSON.parse(payload);
```

Now, if you do `payloadObj.type`, you should be fine.

```js
console.log(payloadObj.type); // PROVIDER_PAYLOAD
```

It should work fine.

> **UPDATE**: ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

If you are getting this error, try following to Parse the payload.

```js
let payloadObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))
```

It should solve the problem for you.